# Visual basic 6.0 hash function

Tags: hash, vb6

In my application I need to hash a string before I save it to a text file. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You should indicate what is the purpose of the hashing, like hiding a password, allowing search, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For what purpose are you using the hash? This matters because some hash algorithms such as MD5 are suitable for some purposes, but not others.

This link shows a [VB6 implementation of MD5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vb6md5hashcode/).

Comment: The link is no longer valid. Broken. @RoadWarrior

Comment: @Ahmad, I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 2):

Example of using CAPICOM to get a hash

Add `CAPICOM.DLL` as project reference

```vb
uses 
  DIM key As String
  DIM sValue As String

  Dim sEncrypedValue as String 

Dim oCAP As CAPICOM.EncryptedData
Set oCAP = New CAPICOM.EncryptedData

With oCAP.
  .Algorithm.KeyLength = CAPICOM_ENCRYPTION_KEY_LENGTH_56_BITS
  .Algorithm.Name = CAPICOM_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM_RC4         
  .SetSecret key
  .Content = sValue 
end with

sEncrypedValue = objCAP.Encrypt(CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64)


To Decrypt:
oCAP.SetSecret key
oCAP.Content = sEncrypedValue 
sValue = oCAP.Decrypt(CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64)
```

Answer (score 1):

(commenting requires 50 rep)

The link that Joel provided is good, but note that you'll need to change the seed value to the standard for it to produce the same CRC32 as everyone else:

```
Optional ByVal Seed As Long = &HEDB88320
```

Hope that saves someone else 30 minutes of work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with CriptoASP. Don't mind about the 'ASP' in the name, it's an ActiveX DLL you can instantiate from VB6. It provides methods for generate random numbers, hashes with MD2, MD4, MD5 and SHA and some kind of encryption/decryption.

You can download it from [CriptoASP](http://www.instisec.com/publico/descargas/?id=3)

I'm sorry, web's language is in spanish, but I think you can undertand the very easy use of the COM with the examples at bottom of [Doc. for CriptoASP](http://www.instisec.com/publico/descargas/criptoasp.asp), just change *Server.CreateObject* with the new object sentence in VB6.

Tell me if you want a translate of the examples or documentation.

To save it to a text file you can use FSO (File System Object).

Answer (score 0):

**I have had very good results with this one, but the implementation is c**

sdbm

this algorithm was created for sdbm (a public-domain reimplementation of ndbm) database library. it was found to do well in scrambling bits, causing better distribution of the keys and fewer splits. it also happens to be a good general hashing function with good distribution. the actual function is hash(i) = hash(i - 1) * 65599 + str[i]; what is included below is the faster version used in gawk. [there is even a faster, duff-device version] the magic constant 65599 was picked out of thin air while experimenting with different constants, and turns out to be a prime. this is one of the algorithms used in berkeley db (see sleepycat) and elsewhere.

```
static unsigned long
sdbm(str)
unsigned char *str;
{
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = c + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;

    return hash;
}
```

**To port it to vb, the calculation goes something like this.
Basically it walks through the characters of the string from left to right, calculating the hash as**

```
newHash = the character (c) + (previousHashValue * 2^6) + 
                              (previousHashValue * 2^16) - 
                               previousHashValue**
previousHashValue = newHash
```

Comment: The whole point of the shl (<<) is to avoid using multiplying by 65599 which is relatively slow. The VB port has TWO multiplications. It would be faster to do this: newHash = the character(c) + (previousHashValue * 65599)